# Call custom confirm dialog in Ajax.Beginform in MVC3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to be able to use a custom jquery dialog or at least be able to change the text of the buttons from OK/Cancel to something else when using the AjaxOptions.Confirm Property in the Ajax.Beginform function.  Like this:

```
<div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Function", "Controller", new { id = theId }, new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "theForm",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            LoadingElementId = "iconGif",
            OnBegin = "OnBegin",
            OnFailure = "OnFailure",
            OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
            Confirm = "Are you sure?" //TODO: Confirm with different dialog?
        }, new { id = "feedback-form" }))
    {
        //Some stuff
        <button onclick="derp()">Submit</button>
    }
</div>
```

**Is there a way to achieve this with Ajax.Beginform through the AjaxOptions.Confirm Property?**

Comment: please refer this answer hope this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/56646824/5475124

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot achieve this with the Confirm property of AjaxOptions. This simply uses the [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.confirm) javascript method which doesn't allow any UI customizations and is browser dependent. You will have to implement this functionality yourself. For example you might want to checkout the [`jQuery UI dialog plugin`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: Thanks @DarinDimitrov I will propably use the Jquery UI Diloag.  It was worth asking anyway :)

Answer (score 7):

I came across this to customize AjaxOptions Confirm text with a value that **has not been created yet when Ajax.Beginform is rendered**. 
For example:
`Confirm="Are you sure you want to create Customer Id" + someValue + "?"`
Finally a found a solution: The approach is regarding a change in submit button behavior with JQuery to pull the value, run my own Confirm dialog and submit the Ajax form if user confirm.

The steps: 
1-  Remove **Confirm** from AjaxOptions and **avoid** set button's type="submit", could be type="button"

```
<div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Function", "Controller", new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "theForm",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            LoadingElementId = "iconGif",
            OnBegin = "OnBegin",
            OnFailure = "OnFailure",
            OnSuccess = "OnSuccess"
            // Confirm option has been removed 
        }, new { id = "feedback-form" }))
    {
        //Some stuff
        <button id="buttonId" type="button" onclick="derp()">Submit</button> //Setting id and type
    }
</div>
```

2- Add following to a js file that it has been refer to in the page or layout.

```
$("#buttonId").click(function () { 
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to create Id "+$("#CustomerId").val() + " ?"))
{
$("#feedback-form").submit(); // Submitting the form if user clicks OK
    }
    });
```

'CustomerId' is the id of some hidden input in the page. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the solution and came here. Although Darin categorically denies the possibility of solution, His answer actually put me on a solution.

**If you can live with supplying the *jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js* file in your bundle, then you can go on with the solution**

***Note: This sample utilizes [Bootstrap Dialog](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)***

Replace the function `asyncRequest(element, options)` in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js with this one

```
   function asyncRequest(element, options) {            
        var confirm = element.getAttribute("data-ajax-confirm");
        if (confirm) {
            BootstrapDialog.confirm({
                title: 'Please Confirm!',
                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
                message: confirm,
                draggable: true,
                callback: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        NewMethod(element, options);
                    }                    
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            NewMethod(element, options);
        }        
    }

    function NewMethod(element, options)
    {
        var loading, method, duration;
        loading = $(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-loading"));
        duration = parseInt(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-loading-duration"), 10) || 0;

        $.extend(options, {
            type: element.getAttribute("data-ajax-method") || undefined,
            url: element.getAttribute("data-ajax-url") || undefined,
            cache: !!element.getAttribute("data-ajax-cache"),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                var result;
                asyncOnBeforeSend(xhr, method);
                result = getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-begin"), ["xhr"]).apply(element, arguments);
                if (result !== false) {
                    loading.show(duration);
                }
                return result;
            },
            complete: function () {
                loading.hide(duration);
                getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-complete"), ["xhr", "status"]).apply(element, arguments);
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                asyncOnSuccess(element, data, xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") || "text/html");
                getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-success"), ["data", "status", "xhr"]).apply(element, arguments);
            },
            error: function () {
                getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-failure"), ["xhr", "status", "error"]).apply(element, arguments);
            }
        });

        options.data.push({ name: "X-Requested-With", value: "XMLHttpRequest" });

        method = options.type.toUpperCase();
        if (!isMethodProxySafe(method)) {
            options.type = "POST";
            options.data.push({ name: "X-HTTP-Method-Override", value: method });
        }

        $.ajax(options);
    }
```

Comment: hmm... this is an interesting solution.  I must apply it for testing.

Comment: Also Please note that this was done in a project on MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom alert like this using sweetalert

```
 $(".SubmitButton").click(function (evt) {
        $("#Form").validate();
        if ($("#Form").valid()) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure want to submit?",
                text: "You will not be able to edit this item after submit",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
                cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                closeOnConfirm: true,
                closeOnCancel: true
            },
                function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                       // swal("Deleted!", "Your item deleted.", "success");

                        $("#Form").submit()
                    }
                });
        } else {
           // error message displays
        }
    });
```