# How to use custom confirm dialog with Ajax Actionlink in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to use the Ajax.ActionLink to make a Delete button for each entry in a table but I cant use the default Confirm function, I need one that I can customise, below I am using Boostrap Modal but I dont thin kthat i've done it right since it's non blocking.
**Actionlink**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ApplicationUser.Id },
    new AjaxOptions {
    HttpMethod = "Delete",
    OnBegin = "return confirmDeletion()"
    },
    new { @class = "delete-link" })
```

This is the function ive made to try get a response from Modal but I dont think it works(my JS is pretty sub par), even if it did I don't think it would stop the Ajax call

```
    function confirmDeletion() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        return document.getElementById("delete-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            return false
        })
        return document.getElementById("cancel-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide')
            return true
        })
    }
```

Any ideas on how to get the Ajax call to wait for some confirmation?, I looked at alertify but looks like it ahs the same issue since it's also nonblocking I believe
Actual problem with this code: Ajax runs either even if you click cancel

Comment: what is your problem now with this code?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Sorry, added the issue at the end of the post, but it's basically that the confirm dialog wont wtop the ajax

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Ajax.BeginForm` to send `id` for make call to `Delete` Action

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", OnComplete = "DeleteComplete", OnFailure = "AjaxErrorPopup", OnBegin = "LoadMask(true)" }, new { id = "DeletePostForm" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("id")
}
```

put common function for delete popup

```
function DeleteLinkTemplate(SubmitFormID,Value) {
    return '<a class=\'fa fa-times fa-lg action-icon text-danger\' href=\'javascript:;\' onclick="CommonConfirmDelete(\'' + SubmitFormID + '\', ' + Value + ')">';
}

function CommonConfirmDelete(SubmitFormID, Value) {
    _CallbackName = SubmitFormID;
    _SubmitFormValue = Value;
    OpenDeleteConfirmDilog();
}

function OpenDeleteConfirmDilog() {
    OpenDilog('#CommonPopupTemplate');
    $("#CommonPopupTemplate .panel-title, #CommonPopupSubmit").html('Delete');
    $("#CommonPopupTemplate .panel-body").html(_CommonDeleteConfirmMessage);
}


function CommonPopupSubmit_Click() {
    if (_CallbackName.indexOf("#")==0||_CallbackName.indexOf(".")==0) {
        $(_CallbackName + " #id").val(_SubmitFormValue);
        $(_CallbackName).submit();
    }
    else {
        window[_CallbackName](_SubmitFormValue);        
    }
}
```

1. Here You have to call `CommonConfirmDelete` from `a` tag delete
   link
2. Make a `Ajax.BeginForm` in your current page for call `Delete`
   Action
3. Send that `formId` and your `ID` to `delete` in
   `CommonConfirmDelete`
4. set `SubmitFormID` and `Value` in global variable `_CallbackName` and `_SubmitFormValue`.
5. Use this variable to set in `CommonPopupSubmit_Click`

When `$(_CallbackName).submit();` fires from your custom popup box. It performs `Ajax.BeginForm` submit. and all things works fine with **Custom** **Confirmationbox**.

Comment: A bit confusing but I'll give it a shot, looks like it'll work better than what i've tried and means I wont have to write the Ajax call

Comment: Yes it works for me. Only follow the steps. It is first time load then till will be easy with passing `formId` and `delete id` to `CommonConfirmDelete`

Comment: Take your time and just understand what is going. Its like `dynamic form submit`.

Comment: Trivedi I did mark you answer as the answered one, unless there was something else I was meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the confirm dialog will obviously not stop the ajax. OnBegin event is generally used to show some progress bar or wait dialog while the ajax completes. What you want to do here is call "ConfirmDeletion" on the click of your delete button instead of making an ajax call and inside confirmDeletion in evenlistener of your "delete-btn" make that ajax call. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is how you will be able to make an ajax call there.

Comment: Bugger, I was hoping I wouldn't have to write my own Ajax call, however only problem I thought of with this is getting the Id(it is a table with multiple delete buttons), so I though maybe use a hidden field, know of a slightly better way of handing this?

Answer (score 0):

Trick : Trigger click event when confirm is true and submit the form else don't submit the form instead of writing your own ajax form submit in jquery

Note: This sample utilizes [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com) to show custom confirm modal popup using [boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions()
    {
       OnBegin = "onBeginSaveFormDetail",
       OnComplete = "loaderhide",
       OnSuccess = "onSuccessFunction",
       OnFailure = "onFailureFunction"
    }))
    { 
      //form content

      <button class="btn btn-success js-submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
      <input type="hidden" id="isconfirm" />
     }
```

-- javascript

```
var onBeginSaveFormDetail = function (event) {
        if ($("#isconfirm").val()) {
            loaderfunction();
            return true;
        }

        return showBootBoxConfirmBox($(this));
    }



var showBootBoxConfirmBox = function($element){
        bootbox.confirm({
            title: "title",
            message: "Are you sure",

            buttons: {
                cancel: {
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    className: 'btn btn-outline-success'
                },
                confirm: {
                    label: 'I Confirm',
                    className: 'btn-success'
                }

            },
            callback: function (result) {
                if (result == true) {
                    //set hidden value isconfirm is true as user click true 
                    //otherwise it is false
                    $element.find("#isconfirm").val(true);

                    // find submit btn using  class ".js-submit-button "
                    $element.find('.js-submit-button').trigger("click");

                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```